# The inertia degree of a field over the decomposition field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, mathematica

$K/F$ is a Galois extension of algebraic number field, $\mathfrak{p}_{i}$ are prime ideals of $K$, and $\mathfrak{p}= \mathfrak{p}_{1}$.

Decompose a prime ideal $\mathcal{p}$ of $F$ in $K$.
$$p(=po_K)=\prod_{i=1}^{g}(\mathfrak{p}_{i})^e$$
The decomposition group of $ \mathfrak{p}:Z=${$\sigma\in Gal(K/F)|\sigma\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{p}$}

The decomposition field of $\mathfrak{p}:K_{Z}=${$\alpha\in K|\sigma\alpha=\alpha, \forall\sigma\in Z$}

Firstly we have

1.#$Gal(K/F)=g$#$Z$  by  $Gal(K/F)=\cup_{i=1}^{g}Z\sigma_{i}$, $\sigma_{i}$ depend on $\sigma_{i}\mathfrak{p}$ are all distinct prime ideals.

2.$[K:F]=efg$, $e$ is the ramification index, $f=[o_{K}/\mathfrak{p}_{i}:o_{F}/\mathcal{p}]$ is the inertia degree(independent of $i$ ).

then my professor’s note said we have $[K:K_{Z}]$=#$Z$，i want to know how to get the equation

Comment: Where exactly is your question? Do you want an explanation for $[K:K_Z] = \#Z$ or for $\#Z = ef$?

Comment: @WhatsUp $[K:K_{Z}]$=#$Z$ Sorry，There's something wrong with my statement

Comment: I guess this is about Galois's fundamental theorem, but how to illustrate that $Z, K_{Z}$ is 1-1 corresponding

Comment: The equation $[K:K_Z]=\#Z$ is simply a fact from Galois theory: the extension $K/K_Z$ is Galois and by the fundamental theorem of Galois theory, it has Galois group $Z$. So the degree of the extension equals the order of $Z$.